# Need div layout to be flexible enough to expand when needed

Tags: css, html

I am porting my application from WPF to HTML/Javascript and am having trouble with the layout that I need for my application.

This layout should take up the entire available screen.  It will actually be put into a jquery ui tab so with the menu, logo, and tabs it technically it won't be the entire screen.  I have gotten parts of this to work but not all together.

The left side is going to have a custom slippy map and I would like it to take up as much space as available both horizontally and vertically.

The right side is going to have some filters at the top and bottom with the middle showing them results from the filters.  The results could be pretty long so it needs to scroll vertically if to much content is pulled from the web server.

All I need help with is the basic layout to support this.  Any help would be appreciated.  You can see my layout drawing below. Thanks in advance!

[image: layout needed]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just decided to use relative positioning and a little javascript.  Spent hours looking for an elegant solution with no results and it only took me a few minutes once I decided to use javascript.  Something like this is so easy to do in WPF so it was surprising.  I basically just attach to the window.onresize event and manually set the height of the right vertically expanding scrollbar.  Thanks for your suggestions anyways.

Comment: I have updated again to use a javascript layout manager that will do more of the heavy lifting for me.  Using a jquery plugin called LayoutManager: http://www.rajeeshcv.com/page/details/6/layoutmanager-jquery-plugin.

Answer (score 0):

In that div, add `style="max-width: 350px; overflow-y: scroll;"`

Answer (score 0):

First, you need something like this (It's called Fluid - Fixed layout), here's an example you can take from Dynamic Drive http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/layouts/item/css-liquid-layout-21-fixed-fluid/. With the exception that you need to "invert" the margins and widths (replacing left to right) because of the example is the opposite of your layout.

Secondly, you need to put your 2nd div (350x50) at the bottom of the page. Some thing you can do, is setting that div so it has the following:

```
#small_box
{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    ...
}
```

The link above does work even on IE6+

Hope It helps.